# Gridview up and down

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a grid in my aspx page. The grid rows should moves up and down when the user click the move up and move down button in the grid.[image]

I disable the First row "UP" button as well as Last row "DOWN" button here.

This works fine but when i insert "PAGING" to the grid Move up and down works only in that page only. For example i cant move my 2nd page data to the 1st page.

Each page the top row up and down button disabled. so that i cant move my 3rd page row data to 1st page.

Here is my code..

```
protected void BindGridview()
    {
        con.Open();
        //cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MobileDetails order by Priority asc", con);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select IDCHECKITEM,CHECKITEM,DESCRIPTION,SORTORDER from CHECKITEM order by SORTORDER asc", con);            
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        gvUserInfo.DataSource = ds;
        gvUserInfo.DataBind();
        GridViewRow FirstRow = gvUserInfo.Rows[0];
        Button btnUp = (Button)FirstRow.FindControl("btnUp");
        btnUp.Enabled = false;
        GridViewRow LastRow = gvUserInfo.Rows[gvUserInfo.Rows.Count - 1];
        Button btnDown = (Button)LastRow.FindControl("btnDown");
        btnDown.Enabled = false;
    }        

    protected void gvUserInfo_RowDataCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        GridViewRow gvrow;
        GridViewRow previousRow;
        if (e.CommandName == "Up")
        {
            index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            gvrow = gvUserInfo.Rows[index];
            previousRow = gvUserInfo.Rows[index - 1];
            int mobilesort = Convert.ToInt32(gvUserInfo.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            //int mobilePriority = Convert.ToInt32(gvUserInfo.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            int mobileId = Convert.ToInt32(gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            int previousId = Convert.ToInt32(previousRow.Cells[0].Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update CHECKITEM set SORTORDER='" + (mobilesort - 1) + "' where IDCHECKITEM='" + mobileId + "'; update CHECKITEM set SORTORDER='" + (mobilesort) + "' where IDCHECKITEM='" + previousId + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Down")
        {
            index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            gvrow = gvUserInfo.Rows[index];
            previousRow = gvUserInfo.Rows[index + 1];
            int mobilesort = Convert.ToInt32(gvUserInfo.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            int mobileId = Convert.ToInt32(gvrow.Cells[0].Text);
            int previousId = Convert.ToInt32(previousRow.Cells[0].Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update CHECKITEM set SORTORDER='" + (mobilesort + 1) + "' where IDCHECKITEM='" + mobileId + "'; update CHECKITEM set SORTORDER='" + (mobilesort) + "' where IDCHECKITEM='" + previousId + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        BindGridview();
    }

    protected void gvUserInfo_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvUserInfo.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGridview();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u should do like this: pls enable the  button for every row except the last row i,e when the paging index ends. U can make use of count to do this.and do the same for the very first item of the list.Hope this will help u.